# not able to use animation for typing game

Tags: javascript

I was trying to build a game, but I am not able to setInterval properly. The word is not getting printed on the screen when I click on the start game button, after 5seconds it directly shows GAME OVER.

```js
var btn= document.querySelector('#btn');

btn.addEventListener("click", myMove);



function myMove() {
    var word = document.querySelector('#word');
    
    var input=document.querySelector('#written');



    var words=['xylophone', 'cat', 'bat', 'chollima'];
    var i=0;
    
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5000);
    function frame() {
        
        word.innerHTML=words[i];
        i = (i < 3) ?( i+1) : 0;
        
      if (input.innerHTML== word.innerHTML) {
        
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        word.innerHTML='GAME OVER';
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id="heading">TYPING GAME</div>
       <label>
           <div id="word"></div>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="written">
       </label>
       <button id="btn">START</button>
 </body>
```

Comment: I think there is some logic error in `if (input.innerHTML== word.innerHTML)`. First off you should use `input.value`, but when you hit Start `input.value` is blank and `word.innerHTML` is equal to the one of the words. So it doesn't enter the first if clause and skips to the else statement. Try adding `console.log(input.innerHTML); console.log(word.innerHTML);` right above that if condition to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there are some issues with your current solution.

1. First of all, **you are changing the [`word.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) for the first time after the `5` second interval, so it will instantly get replaced by *GAME OVER*, so with a difference of some millisecond** the `innerHTML` will be change and you won't be able to see the desired output.
2. Then you are using `input.innerHTML` for your condition **where `innerHTML` only uses for HTML elements which are containing some content within them** (got opening and closing tags) **whilst for taking input value you should use [`input.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text)**.

Thus, in order to make your code work, **you should replace the `innerHTML` in the very first place before executing the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)**. Then after calling the interval **if the condition met you should increment the `i` value and then call your interval again recursively**.

So your final code should be something like this:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
btn.addEventListener("click", myMove);

function myMove() {
  var word = document.querySelector('#word');
  var input = document.querySelector('#written');
  var words = ['xylophone', 'cat', 'bat', 'chollima'];
  var i = 0;
  word.innerHTML = words[i];

  var id = setInterval(frame, 5000);

  function frame() {
    if (input.value == word.innerHTML) {
      clearInterval(id);
      i = (i < 3) ? (i + 1) : 0;
      word.innerHTML = words[i];
      id = setInterval(frame, 5000)
    } else {
      word.innerHTML = 'GAME OVER';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="heading">TYPING GAME</div>
<label>
  <div id="word"></div>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="written">
</label>
<button id="btn">START</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `input.innerHTML`, use [`input.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefvalue) instead:

```js
var btn= document.querySelector('#btn');

btn.addEventListener("click", myMove);



function myMove() {
    var word = document.querySelector('#word');
    
    var input=document.querySelector('#written');



    var words=['xylophone', 'cat', 'bat', 'chollima'];
    var i=0;
    
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5000);
    function frame() {
        
        word.innerHTML=words[i];
        i = (i < 3) ?( i+1) : 0;
        
      if (input.value == word.innerHTML) {
        
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        word.innerHTML='GAME OVER';
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id="heading">TYPING GAME</div>
       <label>
           <div id="word"></div>
           <br>
           <input type="text" id="written">
       </label>
       <button id="btn">START</button>
 </body>
```